# invalid characters in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse the below with in C# with xmldocument. but I can't load it. It says invalid characters. Even in the browser it doesn't display correctly complaining about invalid characters. I need to loop through all  elements in this string.
Can someone please advise what's wrong here?

```
<div><b>Q1.
What is your name?:</b> BTB (Build the bank)</div>
<div><b>Q2.
How old are you?:</b> 29</div>
```

code is this:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(item.Summary);
```

error is: "Illegal characters in path."

Comment: Is it your entire XML document? It must have a root element. Maybe you better use `XmlElement`

Comment: Are you sure it's opening the xml file? I would look to see if "Illegal characters in path" means the path to the xml file.

Comment: What is Item.Summary?

xml.Load(string) Loads the XML document from the specified URL.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Are you trying to pass the xml in as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a file name to load the xml from. Try [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. But now I get the invalid character errros. 
There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 2. Maybe that can be edited by adding a root element to this string.

Comment: But I keep on getting invalid character errors. Maybe this should be parsed as xml?

Comment: But I keep on getting invalid character errors. Maybe this should be parsed as html?

Comment: Yeah. Your sample looks like a snippet of html and its definately not valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

"BTB (Build the bank)" needs to be wrapped in its own tag if this shall be a valid xml. It is valid html though.
Also, xml must have a single top node.

Comment: Yeah, so my options are
1. fix the invalid xml
2. use html document instead. I think codeplex has something right?

Comment: Your first assertion is wrong -- XML elements can have mixed content.